# any better way to validate string pattern after the key word found in txt file?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to check strings in input file and used `re` to compose pattern and parsed input file. Here, input is csv file with multiple lines of sql like script, I want to validate strings in order like first check keyword1, then check ketword2 then check keyword3 in each line of input csv file. By doing this, I used `for` loop but I feel like there is must be better way to handle this. Does anyone suggest how to tackle with this?

**use case**

```
CREATE application vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc WITH some text
CREATE flow flow_src_vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc some text
CREATE stream main_stream_vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc with some text
CREATE OR REPLACE target comp_tgt_vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc some text
```

to handle this, I tried this:

```
kword=['CREATE','CREATE OR REPLACE']
    with open('myinput.txt', 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        nlines = [v for v in lines if not v.isspace()]
        for line in nlines:
            for string in line:
                for word in kword:
                    if string is word:
                        atype=next(string)
                        print('type is', atype)  # such as application, flow, stream
                        
                        if atype in ['application', 'flow', 'steam']:
                            value=next(atype)  ## such as vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc, flow_src_vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc
                            print("name", value)
                        else:
                            print("name not found")
                    else:
                        print("type is not correct")
```

but doing this is not efficient code. I think `re` might do good job here instead. Does anyone have better idea on this?

**objective**:

basically, I need to parse each line where if I spot keyword1 such as `CREATE`, then check word next to ketword1, if nextword is `application`, then print this and check next word of it, where I composed pattern as follow:

```
vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc
pat1=r'^[\vat\d+]_(?:xyz|abs)_rcc_[clm\d+]_trm_(?:soc|aws)'
m=re.match(pat1, curStr, re.M)
```

here is case the eachline has differnt pattern such as

```
pat1=r'^[\vat\d+]_(?:xyz|abs)_rcc_[clm\d+]_trm_(?:soc|aws)'
pat2=r'^\flow_src_[\vat\d+]_(?:xyz|abs)_rcc_[clm\d+]_trm_(?:soc|aws)'
pat3=r'^\main_stream_[\vat\d+]_(?:xyz|abs)_rcc_[clm\d+]_trm_(?:soc|aws)'
pat4=r'^\comp_tgt_[\vat\d+]_(?:xyz|abs)_rcc_[clm\d+]_trm_(?:soc|aws)'
```

how can we make this simple for parsing each line with `re`? any thoughts?

Comment: @flakes I think I removed white space in the begging of each line but expecting to parse patten like `r"^(CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?)(?:OUTPUT TO) (?:FROM|INPUT FROM|INSERT INTO) (TARGET) (\S+) (\S+).*$"`, it become non-captured group in `regex` parser. How should we correct this? here is [input file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/392b6856410e32eac79ce7a9ab29107b/raw/1787d7da12995e3371cad390af9b935eb4a9c290/input.txt) that I want to parse, do you mind to take a look when you have a chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex seems like it can be way simpler than what you're trying. How about this:

```
import re

matcher = re.compile(r"^(CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?) (\S+) (\S+).*$")

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if match := matcher.match(line):
            action, action_type, value = match.groups()
            print(f"{action=}, {action_type=}, {value=}")
```

Outputs:

```
action='CREATE', action_type='application', value='vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc'
action='CREATE', action_type='flow', value='flow_src_vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc'
action='CREATE', action_type='stream', value='main_stream_vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc'
action='CREATE OR REPLACE', action_type='target', value='comp_tgt_vat4_xyz_rcc_clm1_trm_soc'
```

If you want to further validate the values, I would take the results from the first regex and pipe them into more specialized regex's for each case.

```
import re

line_matcher = re.compile(r"^(CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?) (\S+) (\S+).*$")
value_matchers = {
    "application": re.compile(r'^vat\d+_(xyz|abs)_rcc_clm\d+_trm_(soc|aws)'),
    "flow": re.compile(r'^flow_src_vat\d+_(xyz|abs)_rcc_clm\d+_trm_(soc|aws)'),
    "stream": re.compile(r'^main_stream_vat\d+_(xyz|abs)_rcc_clm\d+_trm_(soc|aws)'),
    "target": re.compile(r'^comp_tgt_vat\d+_(xyz|abs)_rcc_clm\d+_trm_(soc|aws)'),
}

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if not (line_match := line_matcher.match(line)):
            print(f"Invalid line: {line=}")
            continue

        action, action_type, value = line_match.groups()
        if not (value_matcher := value_matchers.get(action_type)):
            print(f"Invalid action type: {line=}")
            continue

        if not value_matcher.match(value):
            print(f"Invalid {action_type} value: {line=}")
            continue

        # Do some work on the items
        ...
```

Comment: this is just great. just one question, if I want to parse value such as pattern that I showed above (pat1, pat2, pat3, pat4), can we come up one line of pattern that take care of those 4 separate pattern which have some common? any thoughts?

Comment: should we do like `pattern=r'(?:flow_src|main_stream|comp_tgt)_(vat\d+)_(?:xyz|abs)_rcc_[clm\d+]_trm_soc'`. Do you have better idea maybe?

Comment: Probably keep a dictionary mapping `action_type` to an appropriate regex. One liner gets messy quickly. Think separation of concerns. I'll add what I would do.

Comment: can I ask you one additional question regarding this? I tried to compose pattern like this: `pattern = re.compile(r"^(CREATE(?: OR REPLACE)?)(?:OUTPUT TO) (?:FROM|INPUT FROM|INSERT INTO) (TARGET) (\S+) (\S+).*$")` where expecting to parse key words in each line, but having error instead. Do you have any clue on this? thanks

Comment: @beyond_inifinity I think you probably need to capture the whitespace in the `(?: ...)` as well

Comment: @beyond_inifinity https://regex101.com/ is my goto for testing new regexs

Comment: can you suggest other way around instead of using `:=` operator here: `match := matcher.match(line)`?

Comment: @beyond_inifinity Declare the variable before the if statement. The `:=` assignment operator is a handy helper for declaring a variable and using it immediately. `line_match = line_matcher.match(line); if not line_match: ...`